# Is it possible to change the basic project folder architecture?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have created a new project called myProject1.

Now Visual studio creates in the folder where I placed the project a folder called myProject1 and there it also creates a subfolder myProject1 where it then puts the source files. Thus I have

```
c:\MyProjectLocation\myProject1\myProject1
```

Now my question hwere is: Can I change it so that the 2nd sub folder is not used and the source files put into the first folder? Thus I only get:

```
c:\MyProjectLocation\myProject1
```

As example.

Comment: Don't sweat it.  This matters when you have multiple projects under the same solution.  It will be a bigger PITA if you try to undo this than if you just ignored it.

Comment: I'm using visual studio to program programs in renpy (an python game engine) mostly. There the current structure just gets in my way to comfortably start the programs. Thus the question came up. For c# programs I wouldn't care there for that but in this case it sadly is cumbersome.

Comment: Have you tried removing the project from the solution (right-click, etc), then moving the files to the root of the solution from the project subdirectory, then re-adding the project (Add, Existing Project, etc)?